# jQuery ScrollTo Chrome Fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, scrollto

I've noticed that this doesn't seem to work in Chrome. I found a fix online (that works in the demo) but I can't get it to work for some reason:

Here is the code I have:

```
$('#button-top').bind('click', function(e) {
    try {
        e.preventDefault();
        target = this.hash;
        $('html, body').scrollTo(target, 150);
    } catch (error) {
        alert('error - ' + error);
    }
});
```

If it helps, here is a link to the site I'm building (see the link in the bottom right corner of the page):

http://www.mattpealing.co.uk/_dev/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading an old version (1.4.2) of `jquery.scrollTo`. Change to the [latest version](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) 1.4.13 and it works, see the fiddle in the comments.

Comment: This seems to be the most logical answer to this question, but I still think the use of this plug-in is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery doesn't have any `scrollTo()` function. However, it does have a `scrollTop(position)` function.

This would work (i'm not sure what you meant with your 150):

```
 $('#button-top').bind('click', function(e) {
    try {
        e.preventDefault();
        target = this.hash;
        $('html, body').scrollTop(150);
    } catch (error) {
        alert('error - ' + error);
    }
});
```

If it's an animation you want, this will do the job (with an animation speed of 150ms):

```
$('#button-top').bind('click', function(e) {
    try {
        e.preventDefault();
        target = this.hash;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 150);
    } catch (error) {
        alert('error - ' + error);
    }
});
```

Comment: But he is including the jquery.scrollTo library from https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice that. The question is why use a library when native Jquery does what he wants ?

Comment: Yes, I would also have used the `animate` method instead. Well well.

Comment: ahh wow I didn't realise jQuery had built-in functionality to do that, I'll give it a shot! Thanks